# Nested call to function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA shows a warning when ever I write Javascript like this:

```
someFunction(someOtherFunction());
```

But the explanation is not really helpful:

> "This inspection reports any Javascript function calls used as
>   arguments to another function call."

This is something I do frequently, so what's the potential trap hiding there worth warning of? Or if it's just some coding convention, what's the reason for it?

Comment: In my eyes it is a bad programming style. Properbly that's the reason.

Comment: @reporter i don't see why it is a bad programming style...?

Comment: It doesn't improves the readablilty of source code. And what will happen, if the function does not work correctly (see bottom answer)? It will be hard  to debug. Don't make a big deal with it. It is just my opnion.

Comment: @reporter I understand your opinion, but i must disagree :) As you can see, the answer below is mine, so I understand the concept of it. But let take for example jQuery. There is a lot of times where you have to give a function as argument. The best example : `doSomething($('p'))`. `$()` is a function. It is not by itself a bad practice, it prevent the code repetition. May it be better to save the result in a variable and send the variable to the function? Well, that's a personal opinion but i prefer not since the variable take space in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a warning because most of the time, you want to pass a function reference as an argument. It is mostly used as a callback:

```
someFunction(someOtherFunction);
function someFunction(fn){
    fn.call();
}
```

In that example, `someOtherFunction()` instead of `someOtherFunction` would not work as expect (unless `someOtherFunction` returns a function itself).

`someFunction(someOtherFunction());` work more like a getter.

```
someFunction(someOtherFunction());
function someFunction(int){
    alert(int === 1);//True;
}
function someOtherFunction(){
    return 1;
}
```

It gives a warning because it is a common mistake for new developers.

Comment: Isn't it a legitimate use if you really do mean nested function calls and want to avoid a temporary variable? like `f(g(x))`

Comment: @qwr Never said it wasn't legitimate, just explained why there's a warning. You can disable it in PHPStorm/Webstorm if you want.